# Strange 3-4 meter south offset in new MapDocument

Tags: esri

I'm replacing and old application which shows points of interest in a map. The old app is running against an ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.5.4400 which publishes a base layer map service and a second map service that is a MapDocument with a collection of feature layers with the points to show. Coordinates of features in these layers are in a database in UTM format (European Datum 1950 UTM Zone 30N).

My first application version was running against the same map services, and was working fine, showing the base map and the features exactly in the same positions.

I have now started the next step: to create my own map document and load the same features from database. After some comparing activity, I ended up with a new map service that runs almost perfectly, except that my features are a little (3 or 4 meters) to the south comparing to the same features in the old map.

Funny enought, when I try to highlight some of those features (using a graphical layer I paint a circle at the coordinates and make it blink for a couple of seconds), the point is painted exactly at the position where the feature should be (3 or 4 meters up to the North, just where the old map shows the feature).

I've also tried to start from a copy of the old app's MapDocument, remove all query and XY data layers, and add my queries and my XY data layers there. The result is the same, so I guess the MapDocument itself is OK.

Anyone can give me some light on what can be creating this offset effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols used for the map are of 3D type, like balloons of different colors, so the feature should be down at the balloon's knot. So ArcGIS was doing it well, centering my symbol over the feature's location.

With this in mind, I found the old app's map document added an 8 point Y offset to all symbols. Adding this same offset to all my map's symbols solved the issue.